# Typescript Dynamic type for Object key based on sibling string field

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

i am trying to create a dynamic type based on parts of a sibling 'string type:

example

```js
function getDynamicRoutes(href: string) {
  return (
    href
      .match(/:([A-z]*)/gm)
      .map(s => s.replace(':', ''))
      .reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c]: true }), {})
  )
} 

interface Props {
  // foo/:bar/helloworld/:bat
  href: string;
  
  // { bar: 'string', bat: 'string' }
  substitutes: {
    [k: keyof getDynamicRoutes(Props['href'])]: string;
  }
}
```

expected behaviour
When i provide the above `href` i should get auto-typing for the substitutes Object based on the colon-prepended routes in the href.

So:
`'foo/:bar/helloworld/:bat'`
Will generate a type interface for `substitutes` as:
`{ bar: 'string', bat: 'string' }`

Is this possible?

Comment: You are not allowed to call `getDynamicRoutes` inside interface definition. Furthermore, it is either disallowed to pass `Props['href']` type alias as a function argument. In general you can't use  types where values are expected. Do you want to map `foo/:bar/helloworld/:bat` query parameters into type?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yes i would like to map `:bar` & `:bat` into the `substitutes` object as keys `bar, bat`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to call `getDynamicRoutes` inside interface definition. Furthermore, it is either disallowed to pass Props['href'] type alias as a function argument.
In general you can't use types where values are expected.
If you want to map query string to interface you can do this:

```js
const handle = <Query extends string>(str: Query): ToType<Query> => {
    // implementation is up to You :)
    return null as any
}

type ToType<T extends string, Cache extends Record<string, string> = {}> =
    T extends `${string}/:${infer Prop}/${infer Rest}`
    ? ToType<Rest, Cache & Record<Prop, string>>
    : T extends `${string}/:${infer Last}`
    ? Cache & Record<Last, string>
    : never


// Record<"bar", string> & Record<"bat", string>
const result = handle('foo/:bar/helloworld/:bat')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQzAEwDYFMYF4YB4CKArugE4CeM6AHlOihDNCQJZgDmAfABRMBcMRUmQCU-ACogxZAA7oCxch2xKA3gFgAUDG0wA9LpjMAttIxG6UBFGbhDDQtJhQQMAJohCMXsM06YJdChCEjAYMEJUVBgEBiQyTQBfTU0oGUwJKVlcMUoaOmQGJlY2ABoYAGEEYDhMalp6GAAldFASZFwi9jLOzmwYFQSlLF8dHLr8hgADABIVHoTdXlnWADNSGAAFEhBpBeWwNZIm9GgEyZHtAH4YDLTcZugyyurMADJj1vatne6oFnYOBwLl4brl6gUYDM5n9igslipVusADIxKBnYHXZ41GDvZqfXAox6MGEA4H8MDoABupGSGk0%20g%20IDauAARAAjBAkFm-f69XEtJntdlWbnE3lAjSgSCwAIQCKwHCIFAYLgAchWIBAiw5JF0NUiIAA7kzUMhtVZVcIgA)